# JBOSS Deploy causes error "More than one Application class found in deployment class"

Tags: java, web-applications, jboss, jboss7.x, java-ee-6

I get an error message: " More than one Application class found in deployment class", and I think JBOSS includes a class, what I already added into my Project, and it occurs version conflicts. But how can I know which is this class? And what is `org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.rs.service.JPARSApplication`
class means?

Stacktrace:

```
23:34:41,014 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS015003: Found HockeyProject.ear in deployment directory. To trigger deployment create a file called HockeyProject.ear.dodeploy
23:34:41,018 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "HockeyProject.ear" (runtime-name: "HockeyProject.ear")
23:34:42,120 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS015960: Class Path entry jaxb-api.jar in /C:/Program Files/jboss-as-7.2.0.Final/standalone/deployments/HockeyProject.ear/com.sun.tools.xjc_2.2.0.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
23:34:42,120 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS015960: Class Path entry jaxb-impl.jar in /C:/Program Files/jboss-as-7.2.0.Final/standalone/deployments/HockeyProject.ear/com.sun.tools.xjc_2.2.0.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
23:34:42,120 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS015960: Class Path entry jsr173_1.0_api.jar in /C:/Program Files/jboss-as-7.2.0.Final/standalone/deployments/HockeyProject.ear/com.sun.tools.xjc_2.2.0.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
23:34:42,121 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS015960: Class Path entry activation.jar in /C:/Program Files/jboss-as-7.2.0.Final/standalone/deployments/HockeyProject.ear/com.sun.tools.xjc_2.2.0.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
23:34:42,123 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "null" (runtime-name: "HockeyEJB.jar")
23:34:42,123 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "null" (runtime-name: "HockeyWeb.war")
23:34:42,743 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS015960: Class Path entry jaxb-api.jar in /C:/Program Files/jboss-as-7.2.0.Final/standalone/deployments/HockeyProject.ear/com.sun.tools.xjc_2.2.0.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
23:34:42,743 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS015960: Class Path entry jaxb-impl.jar in /C:/Program Files/jboss-as-7.2.0.Final/standalone/deployments/HockeyProject.ear/com.sun.tools.xjc_2.2.0.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
23:34:42,744 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS015960: Class Path entry jsr173_1.0_api.jar in /C:/Program Files/jboss-as-7.2.0.Final/standalone/deployments/HockeyProject.ear/com.sun.tools.xjc_2.2.0.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
23:34:42,744 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS015960: Class Path entry activation.jar in /C:/Program Files/jboss-as-7.2.0.Final/standalone/deployments/HockeyProject.ear/com.sun.tools.xjc_2.2.0.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
23:34:42,753 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS011401: Read persistence.xml for HockeyEJB
23:34:42,832 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.EjbJndiBindingsDeploymentUnitProcessor] (MSC service thread 1-5) JNDI bindings for session bean named PlayerSessionBean in deployment unit subdeployment "HockeyEJB.jar" of deployment "HockeyProject.ear" are as follows:

    java:global/HockeyProject/HockeyEJB/PlayerSessionBean!hu.dbit.ejb.PlayerSessionBean
    java:app/HockeyEJB/PlayerSessionBean!hu.dbit.ejb.PlayerSessionBean
    java:module/PlayerSessionBean!hu.dbit.ejb.PlayerSessionBean
    java:global/HockeyProject/HockeyEJB/PlayerSessionBean
    java:app/HockeyEJB/PlayerSessionBean
    java:module/PlayerSessionBean

23:34:42,843 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-5) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.subunit."HockeyProject.ear"."HockeyWeb.war".INSTALL: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit."HockeyProject.ear"."HockeyWeb.war".INSTALL: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase INSTALL of subdeployment "HockeyWeb.war" of deployment "HockeyProject.ear"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:127) [jboss-as-server-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.4.GA.jar:1.0.4.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.4.GA.jar:1.0.4.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS011231: More than one Application class found in deployment class org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.rs.service.JPARSApplication and class org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.rs.service.JPARSApplication
    at org.jboss.as.jaxrs.deployment.ResteasyDeploymentData.merge(ResteasyDeploymentData.java:60)
    at org.jboss.as.jaxrs.deployment.JaxrsIntegrationProcessor.deploy(JaxrsIntegrationProcessor.java:122)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:120) [jboss-as-server-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    ... 5 more

23:34:42,852 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 53) JBAS011402: Starting Persistence Unit Service 'HockeyProject.ear/HockeyEJB.jar#HockeyEJB'
23:34:42,853 INFO  [org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 53) HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: HockeyEJB
    ...]
23:34:42,867 INFO  [org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.ConnectionProviderInitiator] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 53) HHH000130: Instantiating explicit connection provider: org.hibernate.ejb.connection.InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider
23:34:42,873 INFO  [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 53) HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
23:34:42,874 INFO  [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionFactoryInitiator] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 53) HHH000268: Transaction strategy: org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jta.CMTTransactionFactory
23:34:42,875 INFO  [org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 53) HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
23:34:43,093 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment "HockeyProject.ear" was rolled back with the following failure message: 
{
    "JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.subunit.\"HockeyProject.ear\".\"HockeyWeb.war\".INSTALL" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit.\"HockeyProject.ear\".\"HockeyWeb.war\".INSTALL: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase INSTALL of subdeployment \"HockeyWeb.war\" of deployment \"HockeyProject.ear\"
    Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS011231: More than one Application class found in deployment class org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.rs.service.JPARSApplication and class org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.rs.service.JPARSApplication"},
    "JBAS014771: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.deployment.unit.\"HockeyProject.ear\".deploymentCompleteService is missing [jboss.deployment.subunit.\"HockeyProject.ear\".\"HockeyWeb.war\".deploymentCompleteService]"]
}
23:34:43,097 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 53) JBAS011403: Stopping Persistence Unit Service 'HockeyProject.ear/HockeyEJB.jar#HockeyEJB'
23:34:43,109 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment null (runtime-name: HockeyWeb.war) in 16ms
23:34:43,109 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment null (runtime-name: HockeyEJB.jar) in 16ms
23:34:43,145 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment HockeyProject.ear (runtime-name: HockeyProject.ear) in 52ms
```

Comment: Add full stack trace here. this exception can come because of many reasons.

Comment: Are you trying to use EclipseLink for JPA?